# How do I count the number of times a value with a certian criteria occurs within an conditional index of cells

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, formula

I have the below formula that works great to find a percentage that I am looking for:

```
=SUM((COUNTIF(B12:B10002,">=9"))/(COUNT(B12:B10002)))
```

What I now need to do with the COUNT and COUNTIF is make the range conditional to the preceding column.

- Range A12:A10000 indicates a date
- Range B12:B10000 indicates a number between 1-10
- Cell A5 indicates a date

I would like to know how many times a 9 or 10 occurs in B12:B10000, but only if the preceding cell in A12:A10000 is equal to A5

I have tried INDEX MATCH, but it only renders "1" (meaning true) or it gives me the number 10 which is the first cell in B12

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS()` for this. Much like `COUNTIF` but it will accept multiple criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(A12:A10000,A5,B12:B10000,">=9")
```

If you are using an older version of Excel that doesn't support `COUNTIFS()` you can use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A12:A10000=A5)*(B12:B10000>=9)*1)
```